# Physics of Snow Globe

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, simulations

What is the physics behind snow flakes inside a 3D [snow globe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snow_globe)? If I were to implement a snow globe in computer graphics what kind of model do I need to the flakes motion like a real snow globe?

What field of physics does this problem belong to?

Comment: Fluid dynamics / hydrodynamics, I'd guess. But you need to decide if physical accuracy is important, because you certainly don't need a full physics simulation to sufficiently convey the idea of a snow globe.

Answer (score 2):

This is low-Reynolds number particle sedimentation.

It turns out that the problem is strikingly difficult, despite the simplicity of the setup and even of the equations (Stokes plus dynamics of pointwise solid particles). Check the webpage of [E Guazzelli](http://iusti.univ-provence.fr/gsite/document.php?project=iusti&pagendx=11374) who's been working a lot on this.

However, I believe you can get a fair rendering with simply a diffusion term coupled with a gravity one (actually, for a "nice" snow globe, you want to minimize collective movements so that it looks like the "ideal" quiet snow fall)